# Why doesn't lookahead match on either side of the following term?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm experimenting with using lookaheads for checking if a string contains a pattern at any position, however, I'm struggling a bit to understand it.

The pattern `(?=.*px)[\d]+` should match (to my understanding) any digits (as groups, therefore 12 would be one match) that also have either before or after the letters p and x, in that order, regardless of the position (`.*`).

That pattern works as expected while using "12px", matching the 12 but not the px. However, if I use px12 it doesn't match the 12 anymore and I'm struggling to understand why. Also, the string "12pxpx12px12" matches the first and second 12 as both have px after it, but not the last one.

Here are some examples for reference:
[image: Regex example]

I'd appreciate it if someone could explain to me what is wrong in terms of what I'm looking forward to achieving and how the proper way of writing the regex would be.

Comment: Given the input string `12pxpx12px12`, what exactly do you want to match and why?

Comment: I'm looking to get a better understanding about lookaheads. My logic with the pattern I placed in the example is that it will match any sequence of digits that have either before or after the characters "px, so the (?=.*px) would make a match when the px is found at any location because of the ".*" part.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean, so `(?=.*px)` "translates" to "Match any digits that are followed by any amount of characters, and then `px`" rather than "Match the digits of a string that have px either before or after them"?. If so, what would the proper regex be?

Comment: When you use lookahead, both the lookahead and what comes after the lookahead must match whatever point you're at now.  In your example, you're saying that you want to find some point in the string that matches `.*px`, throws that way, and then also immediately matches 12.  You've got that at the beginning of the string for `12px`.  But for `px12`, there is no point in the string that immediately matches both `.*px` and `12`.  By the time you can match the 12, you're beyond the px.  Same for your third example

Comment: `(?=.*px)` asserts that the current location in the string is to be followed by zero or more (`*`) characters other than a line terminator, then `'px'`. Since you have `(?=.*px)[\d]+` (which is the same as `(?=.*px)\d+`), one or more digits must follow the current location in the string. If, for example, `\d` matched `23`, then the first two characters matching `.*` must be `23` . The string might be `'23px'` for example, in which case `'23'` would be returned. If, however, the string were `'23 my dog has fleas px'`, `'23'` would be returned as well.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the title. If you'd like to clarify it further, by all means [edit] it yourself. For tips on writing a good title in the future, see [ask].

Comment: Thanks Cary! Okay, so I understand now why it matches 12px but not px12. Now the matter becomes, what regex should be used to where it matches any digits (and only the digits) that have px either before or after? Probably something like a `(px\d+ | \d+px)` (untested) can work for the whole statement althogh if I look for only the digits it'd failI think, is there a way to refactor the statement to achieve the same goal but using lookahead?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andrea! I'll definitely do my best to improve the title next time :)

Comment: I believe in summary the main question becomes around how to match the digits after a pattern (in this case, 2 letters) without matching those letters, while also being able to match those digits if the letters comes after them. This last part can be achieved by using `(?=\d+px)\d+`, which instead of matching anything before the `px`, it matches only when there is digits preceeding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookahead `(?=px)` means "the substring immediately *following* this point is `px`", and `\d+` means "the substring at this point is multiple digits". Those are mutually incompatible statements. Lookarounds are **zero-width** assertions, meaning that if you wanted to match something *before* a concrete assertion like `\d+`, you can't use lookahead, you need to use lookbehind.

Off the top of my head, the best solution I can think of uses exclusive-or:

```
(?<=px)\d+|\d+(?=px)
```

[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RvOVab/1)

Comment: LMK if you're confused about any aspect of this explanation. I'm not sure I phrased it very well.

Comment: So, in summary, lookaheads on this context translates to something like "Whatever you search needs to be before this pattern" or "This lookahead pattern needs to be ahead of whatever you search", so if I search for a number before the word cat, the cat is the lookahead and the number the actual pattern to target. On the other hand, lookbehind translates to "Whatever you search needs to be after this pattern" or "This lookbehind pattern needs to be behind of whatever you search", which in the prev example allows to maintain the number as the pattern as it'll look behind it for the look behind?

Comment: Thanks for explaining it by the way!:)

Comment: @Fernando Welcome! I think you're getting it, though the way you're explaining it isn't totally clear.

Comment: Could you explain me what's the difference between lookahead and look behind?:) I think I'm a little confused there

Comment: @Fernando One looks ahead and one looks behind. What else is there to explain? If you want a full-on tutorial, maybe try [this one from regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). **Edit**: not trying to be glib, I'm just not sure why you're confused.

Comment: THanks! I got it now, I was following a rather badly made example that said lookaheads where the same as lookbehinds and were used to just check if at least something was preset anywhere on the string. Thanks a lot!